# Storing .NET object to memory and leaving it there after exit

Tags: c#, memory, configuration, memory-mapped-files

I was wondering if there was a way to load an object in memory and leave it there after the program exist. I want to do this to share configuration info across a WCF REST service without having to go to the disk for serialization/deserialization every time the config is read. An issue I am having is there is no guarantee that something is always running to "hold" the object.

I am using C# and .NET 4.0.

Here is some psuedo code that models what I will/hope to do:

```
variable localmemoryobject
if memoryObject does not exist then
    create the memory object
end if 
copy the memory object into localmemoryobject
done
```

I am looking into memory-mapped files to accomplish this and wasn't sure if this was appropriate for my issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a Windows service app for your configuration and keep that alive?

Comment: I thought about doing this, but how would I access the service in a simple manner? I don't want to open up a TCP connection every time just to get config.

Comment: TCP? If it's on the same machine you could go for IPC instead

Comment: I'll give it to you, I ended up using memory-mapped files in a Windows Service.

Comment: told you.. anyway, if you still need to access the service from other machines consider using a proxy service that you can access on the local machine using IPC and that keeps a TCP connection open to the other machine(s). If at all possible I'd keep it local though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep some data in memory, then there will need to be at least one process that remains running to store it. You may want to have a small process that you use for storing these in-memory objects (like [memcached](http://memcached.org/), for example) and then have your WCF services start-up and shutdown without worrying about serializing data to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Use Enterprise Libraries Caching Blocks within your WCF service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649551.aspx

Your WCF service will need to read the config once, and then it will be cached in memory for future calls, until either the configured cache-expiry interval is passed, or you restart the service.

Comment: But I am using WCF REST, the service isn't "started" per say, it's hosted in IIS. I like the idea, if I can get it to work.

Comment: OK - http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2008/10/29/adding-caching-to-wcf-restful-services-using-the-rest-starter-kit.aspx may be more appropriate then than Ent Libs.

Comment: That type of caching is for data being returned from the service. The configuration object is never served, therefore, it won't be cached through traditional means.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly Windows' Memory Mapped Files API can be of use to you.

See more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908742.aspx